# Printing out source hierarchy with large TCL project

Tags: tcl

So I am working with a large TCL project and thought it would be cool to build a treeview of how files were being source in the project. I modified the source command to do the following:

```
rename ::source ::real_source

proc ::source args {
    set file_handle [open "file_source.tcl" a]
    puts $file_handle $args
    puts $file_handle $argv0
    close $file_handle
    uplevel 1 ::real_source $args
}
```

Which works and saves all of the files being sourced but I was wondering if anyone had any ideas on how I could determine which files are calling the source command?

Another interesting issue I am running into is that my new source procedure seems to only work in some files. File A sources File B and all of the sources in File B seem to work correctly but anything under that seems to go back to using the old source procedure. Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: The issue with different files doing “something surprising” looks a bit complex. Please open another question for that. (Too many things in one question.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[info script]` will give you the name of the file invoking `source`

Example:

a.tcl

```
rename ::source ::real_source
proc ::source args {
    puts "[info script] sources $args"
    uplevel 1 ::real_source $args
}
source b.tcl
```

b.tcl

```
puts "in file b"
source c.tcl
```

c.tcl

```
puts "in file c"
```

outputs

```
a.tcl sources b.tcl
in file b
b.tcl sources c.tcl
in file c
```